# R - Using str_detect function with Arabic text [or other right to left languages], formatting messed up in R Studio

Tags: r, arabic, stringr

I'm trying to use the str_detect function to check for a regex expression where the text is in Arabic. Ideally, if I wanted to check a column where the value == 'x', I would have used "^x$" in my regex. This time, the text is in Arabic so when I try to add the caret and $, formatting goes for a toss in R Studio.
Any easy way to tackle this other than writing the script in a text editor and pasting it in R?
Example code:

```
data_querytype <- subset %>%
mutate(queryType = 
ifelse(str_detect
(`Search term`, 
"يلا شباب"),"Al Shabab",
"Other"))
```

Comment: Which operating system are you working on? I get a similar problem with Russian/Cyrillic in Windows, unless I set the locales properly. In *nix operating systems (linux, OsX) I never get those problems.

Comment: Hi @NicolásVelásquez , I'm on Windows 10. How do you go about with setting locales?

Comment: You will need to change Win10 default language to Arabic.
If this is too cumbersome, I suggest you try to run R from a Docker or a Virtual machine running Linux. *nix SO use UTF-8 by default, which is an encoding that is much more robust to handle non western characters.